# How does the LM317 bypass adjustment terminal reduce ripple amplification?

Tags: lm317

According to the [LM317 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm317.pdf) it says that the adjustment terminal must be bypassed to ground to improve ripple rejection, so that the ripples aren't amplified.

Could anyone explain how this is possible in detail?

I have done quite a lot of research but I don't understand how the adjustment terminal and ripple rejection are linked.

Comment: How about a link to the datasheet you are referencing?

Comment: It doesn't actually say "must". It *can* be bypassed for a typical improvement of about 7 dB. It probably is related to the "non-idealness" of the current sources within the chip, by reducing the AC impedance of that node to ground, relative to the very large (but still finite) impedance to Vin.